# Inserting array values into a table by order

Tags: php, arrays

I got an array of 624 images, witch are named like so:

```
1n1e.png
1n2e.png
..
2n1e.png
2n2e.png
```

and so on. the maximum 'n' value is 13 and maximum 'e' value is 48, i mean this - `13n48e`.

I want to create a 13x48 table, and put all these images accordingly.

```
1n1e is located in bottom left corner, 
13n1e is at the top left corner, 
13n48e at the top right corner, 
1n48e at the bottom right corner.
```

Edit: i had this old code but it doesnt work how i want to:

```
echo "<table border='1'>";
$oldIndex=0;
$row=1;
foreach($images as $image)
{
    if(substr($image,0,1)!=$oldIndex)
    {
    if($row>1){echo "</tr>";}

    echo "<tr>";
    $oldIndex=substr($image,0,1);
    $row++;
    }
    echo "<td>$image</td>";

}

echo "</table>";
```

Comment: That sounds nice.  What have you done?  Run into any errors?

Comment: @Jason eddited with old code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.. something like this?

```
echo "<table>";
for( $n =13; $n >= 1; $n-- )
{
    echo "<tr>";
    for ( $e = 1; $e <= 48; $e++ )
    {
         echo "<td>";
         echo image $n $e
         echo "</td>";

    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Ye i think its like this but i need it upside down, i mean `1n1e` is top left corner, where i want it to be bottom left corner